# How to access child components in Angular that are projected using ng-content

Tags: angular

I have a component that can be used as a template

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-template',
    templateUrl: './customtemplate.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./customtemplate.component.css']
})
export class CustomTemplateComponent { 
    @ContentChild('button', {read: ElementRef}) button: ElementRef; 
}
```

customtemplate.component.html

```
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

and i used it in another component parent.component.html and in that i have included a child component

```
<app-template>
    Some Content
    .......
    <app-child></app-child>
</app-template>
```

In child component, i have a button with reference #button
child.component.ts

```
@Component({
      selector: 'app-child',
      templateUrl: './child.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
})
export class ChildComponent { }
```

child.component.html

```
<div>
    <button #button></button>
</div>
```

How do i access this button from template component. I tried to access using @ContentChild but it is undefined

Comment: In which lifecycle hook you tried to access this contentc child?

Comment: You can't access the button of the child directly. You have to access `app-child`, then accessing the button (button-reference should be public on app-child)

Comment: i tried to access in NgAfterContentInit

Comment: In the angular documentation, they have mentioned like it is not possible to access other component's template element. But is there any workaround for that?.

Comment: @enno.void : How can i access the button after accessing app-child?. I tried ContentChild to refer the app-child component. After that, what i need to do to get the button?

Comment: @AjaySankaran https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hegae9

Comment: @enno.void Thank you very much

Comment: I'm also interested in this and the stackblitz above doesn't work anymore @enno.void

Comment: @AsGoodAsItGets I recreated it for you
https://stackblitz.com/edit/access-element-of-transcluded-compoentn?file=src/app/parent/parent.component.ts

Comment: @enno.void thanks! 